# Artemis master node don't switch back to live after restart

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have Artemis configuration (shared storage) with following ha-policy (for master and slave):

Master:

```
<ha-policy>
  <shared-store>
    <master>
      <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
    </master>
  </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

Slave:

```
<ha-policy>
  <shared-store>
    <slave>
      <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
    </slave>
  </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

i am doing the following steps:

1. Stop Master

> ./artemis-service stop

Backup is now live:

```
2020-09-22 10:51:57,172 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221010: Backup Server is now live
```

2. Start Master

> ./artemis-service start

Master don't switch to live:

```
2020-09-22 10:53:01,128 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
2020-09-22 10:53:01,489 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221031: backup announced
```

Is this the correct behavior? Why doesn't the master server become live after restart?

But If I stop the backup server, the master becomes live.

Server version 2.11

I tried to reproduce this on 2.15. Artemis 2.15 works correctly.

Comment: Have you tried this on the [latest release](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/)?

Comment: Thank you! I will try now, but we'll be using the old version for a while.  Is this a version 2.11 bug?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific fix that would necessarily resolve your problem, but it's always a good idea to test on the latest release simply to rule out the possibility that the issue has already been fixed. It would be a big waste of time to do all the work to reproduce and investigate the problem only to find later that it had already been resolved. Version 2.11.0 is pretty old at this point. Hundreds of issues have been resolved in later releases.

Comment: Ok! I am trying to reproduce the problem in  2.15.  Am I correct in my understanding that the config looks correct?

Comment: Everything works correctly at 2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks good.

Please move to [the latest release](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/). I believe there were some issues with file locking that have been resolved since 2.11.0.

You can find upgrade instructions in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html).

Comment: Thank! Is it enough to unpack the new version and update the variable ARTEMIS_HOME to update the server?

Comment: Thank you Justin. I already updgraded my broker to 2.15. i faced a problem in Admin Console GUI 2.15: It feels like the page is refreshed every second and the address tree on the left is reset. Where can I describe this error? On github? in Jira?

Comment: Use the [ActiveMQ User Mailing List](http://activemq.apache.org/contact/#mailing).